# Shortcut to Radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

Can you help me how to solve this radical equation?

Solve for $x$: $\sqrt{\dfrac{5+x}{x-1}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{x-1}{5+x}}+\dfrac{3}{2}.$

Comment: $x = 3$........  Put the radicals on the left, square both sides, manipulate and solve.  You'll see how the "cross" term simplifies nicely.

Comment: multiply through by $\sqrt {x-1}\sqrt {5+x}$ eliminating the fractions, and some of the radicals.  Isolate the terms containing radicals on one side of the equals sign, and the terms without on the other.  Square both sides.  Repeat if necessary (I don't think it will be).

Comment: I tried to let $a=x+5$ and $b=x-1$ for easy manipulation but i got lost through the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain gives $-5<x<1$ and we have
$$2(x+5)=2(x-1)+3\sqrt{(x+5)(x-1)}$$ or
$$(x+5)(x-1)=16$$ or
$$x^2+4x-21=0$$ or
$$(x-3)(x+7)=0,$$ which gives
$$x=3.$$

Comment: Can you help me with this question: $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles with $AB=AC.$ Let $D$ be the foot of the altitude from $A$ on $BC,$ and let $E$ be the point on side $AC$ such that $DE$ bisects $\angle ADC.$ If $\angle ADC = 67,$ what is the measure of $\angle BAC?$

Answer: $44^{\circ}$

Comment: @user484792 It seems that you mean $\measuredangle DEC=67^{\circ}.$. If so $\measuredangle DAE=67^{\circ}-45^{\circ}=22^{\circ},$ which gives $\measuredangle BAC=44^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the term $\sqrt{\dfrac{5+x}{x-1}} =t$. Note that we have $x \in R \setminus (-5,1]$

Then 
$$t = \frac{1}{t}+\frac{3}{2} \\
2t^2-3t-2=0\\
(t-2)\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0$$

So you need to check if these values satisfy original equation.

As pointed in comments below, the surd cannot be **negative**. Thus we only have solution corresponding to $t=2$, and no solution corresponding to $t = -1/2$.

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{5+x}{x-1}} =2 \\
\dfrac{5+x}{x-1}=4 $$

Giving $x = 3$.

Comment: You have the same answer as me, but got it faster +1

Comment: I was surprised that no one gave this answer, not even in comments! Then saw your answer. Didn't have to delete it, but its ok :)

Comment: You don't even have to input these values in the initial equation: one sees at once that  its domain of validity is $(-\infty,-5)\cup(1,+\infty)$, so only $2$ is a solution.

Comment: Ha I feel so silly. Yes there's only one solution. Can also be said because the expression is monotonic. Thank you bernard and john lou!

Answer (score 0):

Raise this equation to power two. Etc. Be careful, analyze your process carefully and cleanly since squaring is not quite a reversible operation.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer. Please add some detail so it becomes more useful.

Comment: @JohnLou, I see that this forum is not my cup of tea. I apologize, my mistake (and, consistently, I am out of here, no more problem).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a hint, just make sure you add a little more detail next time :-)